# Drupal: add a taxonomy vocabulary field to my custom content type

Tags: field, taxonomy, vocabulary

How I can add a taxonomy vocabulary field to my custom content type to my module?

My objective is when I create a new content(of my custom content type, of course) give me the posibility of select the term which I  want to reference  inside the vocabulary

Thanks for all the help you can give me

Answer (score 1):

This sounds pretty common use of taxonomy. Have you seen this? http://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/taxonomy/content